# How to go back to a function in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have some buttons when a user click one of them they update the content of the page through ajax then the buttons are hidden and some new buttons are available for user. The problem is when i hit the back button it doesn't go back to the previous function. I want the user to go back to the previous set of buttons here is my code :

```
$(".buttonset1").click(function() {
    $('#div1').css("display","none");
    id = $(this).attr("value");
    query = 'ajax.php?id='+id;
    myQuery(query);
    $('#div2').css("display","block");
});

$(".buttonset2").click(function() {
    $('#div2').css("display","none");
    value = $(this).attr("value");
    query = 'ajax.php?id='+id+'&var1='value;
    myQuery(query);
    $('#div3').css("display","block");
});
```

Now div2 is shown to the user.... myQuery function does the ajax query

```
function myQuery(url) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("sql").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(); 
}
```

Comment: pressing the back button of the browser would go to the previous url, javascript code will be reloaded (and variables data lost) if you reload the page. There is no "back" for javascript functions, you'll have to store your previous variables before update and write yourself a function to put them back in (not clicking the back browser button thought)

Comment: how about using history.pushstate .... and is there any alternate way to do this?

Comment: where did you see that pushstate() method? I'm guessing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState%28%29_method ?

Comment: ok so that is for browser's history of visited webpages, not a local storage or smth. you'll need to save your variables and bring them back yourself

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky yeah look at the code myQuery() the variables are passed $_GET so I guess data wont be lost until the browser is closed right?

Comment: no, you don't have them in the url of your page because you are making an ajax request, you can easily save them in your php code - in your $_SESSION variable and then they will be kept until the browser is closed (even if your page's tab is closed and opened again they'll still be there)

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it was pretty simple

```
 History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state 
    var url = State.url;    
    myQuery(url);   
});
```